# OptaPlanner HelloWorld VehicleRoutingSolution problem lacks an easyScoreCalculatorClass or an incrementalScoreCalculatorClass

Tags: java, optaplanner, vehicle-routing

I'm trying to run a modified version of the `org.acme.vehiclerouting.solver.SolverManagerTest` class from the **optaplanner-distribution-8.29.0.Final** bundle I've just downloaded. Modified, as in I've copied it to my own project. However, I am unable to create a `SolverFactory`, probably because I'm not running this in Spring, so I'm trying to create my SolverManager by hand instead of relying on `@Inject`.

```java
    VehicleRoutingSolution problem = DemoDataBuilder.builder().setMinDemand(1).setMaxDemand(2)
            .setVehicleCapacity(25).setCustomerCount(75).setVehicleCount(6).setDepotCount(2)
            .setSouthWestCorner(new Location(0L, 43.751466, 11.177210))
            .setNorthEastCorner(new Location(0L, 43.809291, 11.290195)).build();

    SolverManager<VehicleRoutingSolution, Long> solverManager;
    SolverConfig solverConfig = new SolverConfig()
            .withSolutionClass(VehicleRoutingSolution.class)
            .withEntityClasses(Vehicle.class)
            .withTerminationSpentLimit(Duration.ofSeconds(3));


    SolverFactory<VehicleRoutingSolution> configFactory = SolverFactory.create(solverConfig);
```

The above fails with

> *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The scoreDirectorFactory lacks a configuration for an easyScoreCalculatorClass or an incrementalScoreCalculatorClass.*

What should I be using for my ScoreDirectorFactory? Should I try to get @Inject working instead? I'd prefer to be able to do this configuration by hand, there's an awful lot of magic going on when running the examples.

Answer (score 2):

Found it:

```
    SolverConfig solverConfig = new SolverConfig()
            .withSolutionClass(VehicleRoutingSolution.class)
            .withEntityClasses(Vehicle.class)
            .withScoreDirectorFactory(new ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig().withConstraintProviderClass(VehicleRoutingConstraintProvider.class))
            .withTerminationSpentLimit(Duration.ofSeconds(3));
```

I was looking for clues in .java files, but it's defined in `vehicleRoutingBenchmarkConfig.xml`

```xml
      <scoreDirectorFactory>
        <constraintProviderClass>org.optaplanner.examples.vehiclerouting.score.VehicleRoutingConstraintProvider</constraintProviderClass>
        <initializingScoreTrend>ONLY_DOWN</initializingScoreTrend>
      </scoreDirectorFactory>
```